# System date formatting not using django locale

Tags: python, django, localization, date-format

Trying to understand L10N implementation into Django, Here are my settings

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'fr-FR'
USE_L10N = True
```

If I try

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('2012-05-30 15:30', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
      .strftime('%c')
```

It will give me `'Wed May 30 15:30:00 2012'` that is the *EN* locale. However the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/i18n/localization/#format-localization) is saying:

> [...] Two users accessing the same content, but in different language, will see date and number fields formatted in different ways, depending on the format for their current locale [...]

Are they talking about the locale set for their respective browser ?
If not, how can I set it to french by default for example ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Django's localization works in the context of Django templates and forms, and can not travel up the chain to Python's internal datetime representations:

```
When using Django's formatting system, dates and numbers on templates 
will be displayed using the format specified for the current locale. 
...Django will also use localized formats when parsing data in forms.
```

So if you have `USE_L10N = True` and a user with the region `FR` enters `10,45` into a form, that will be interpreted to mean `10.45` in the English decimal system. Similarly, the output of a template tag like `{{ value|date:"SHORT_DATE_FORMAT" }}` will vary based on the user's locale.

However, the Python internal `strftime('%c')` doesn't access Django's settings, and instead refers to the locale set on the machine on which it is installed. You can retrieve and change the locale settings Python points to with:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('2012-05-30 15:30', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M').strftime('%c')
'Wed May 30 15:30:00 2012'
>>> import locale
>>> locale.getlocale()
(None, None)
>>> locale.getdefaultlocale()
('en_US', 'UTF-8')
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "fr_FR.UTF-8")
'fr_FR.UTF-8'
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('2012-05-30 15:30', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M').strftime('%c')
'Mer 30 mai 15:30:00 2012'
```

Or by setting the environment variable `$LANG`.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. I forgot to notice that `datetime` has obviously nothing to do with Django :) Now if I need to send a list of formatted dates by JSON, which would be the best way to format it depending on the users locale ?

Comment: I guess that would require actually assembling the JSON after you are aware of the user's locale. Try this? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/i18n/

Comment: New question asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802680/django-accessing-request-meta-data-from-production)

Comment: In case the current system locale is already set to the desired locale, but still `strftime` is not honoring it, it may be due to the `datetime` module behavior. See this related [issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue29457).