# datetime.now() returns wrong day in Django application

Tags: python, django

My Django application (nginx, uwsgi stack) requests the current day by calling datetime.now():

```
def get_drinks(request, drink_type):
    current_day = datetime.today().strftime("%w")
    current_day_string = datetime.today().strftime("%A")
```

And I show the current day on my website. For some bizarre reason, it is returning Friday, instead of Thursday (today). My server time is:

```
server:~$ date
Thu Apr  9 18:51:02 PDT 2015
```

And when I run datetime.now() in the python shell, I get Thursday as well:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%A")
'Thursday'
```

What's the issue here?

Comment: It's currently Friday in UTC - is it possible that Django is reporting in UTC?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`datetime.datetime.now()` is not aware of timezone so gets the current time in system's local timezone. You should set `TIME_ZONE` to `America/Los_Angeles` (PST/PDT) and `USE_TZ` to `True` in your settings.py file so that all date values created within your application are always timezone aware as long as you import from `django.utils.timezone`.

Please see the [timezone](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/timezones/) documentation for more information.

```
TIME_ZONE = "America/Los_Angeles"
USE_TZ = True
```

---

```
>>> from django.utils import timezone

>>> print timezone.now()
datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 10, 2, 17, 10, 839067, tzinfo=<UTC>)

>>> print timezone.localtime(timezone.now())
datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 9, 19, 17, 10, 839067, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/Los_Angeles' PDT-1 day, 17:00:00 DST>)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change Django's locale setting.

here is another question and answer for same problem.

[System date formatting not picking up django locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10801397/django-change-default-locale)